# Where is plist file storing NSUserDefaults in Xcode 6

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6

I have saved a bunch of NSUserDefaults in my app and now I am trying to find out where in the world is the plist file for for my app in Xcode 6. Here is the path for my apps document dir.

```
/Users/xxx/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/676A8C61-67E4-43E0-A051-DA8BD84A84F5/data/Containers/Data/Application/B2E3C89C-48B7-4429-BBE3-FB830CD040F2/Documents
```

I have searched everywhere in the folder but I couldn't find where the plist file is? Is it located somewhere else? I need to manually edit a NSUserDefaults in it.

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"1" forKey:@"firstTimeLaunch1257"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `NSUserDefaults` plist file is in the `CoreSimulator/Devices/<device id>/data/Library/Preferences` folder.

This folder contains the `NSUserDefaults` files for all apps installed in that simulator.

The name of the plist file will match your app's bundle id.

Comment: The plist file I see has non of the keys set in the App. In fact, it has only two keys set by FBSDK... Current path is /Users/<username>/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/<ID>/data/Containers/Data/Application/<ID>/Library/Preferences/<AppName>.plist

Answer (score 1):

**Update in 27 Jul 2017**
`xcode8.3.1` `iOS8.0` `macos Sierra 10.12.5`

The path could be the following in simulator for developer,

> /Users/`<UserName>`/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/`<DeviceID>`/data/Containers/Data/Application/`<ApplicationID>`/Library/Preferences/`<YourApp>.plist`

The path mentioned in the selected answer is for Apple Plist.

> /Users/`<UserName>`/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/`<DeviceId>`/data/Library/Preferences
>   In the path, the files are `com.apple.<AppleStuff>.plist`